# iOS navigation-bar animate background on loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Recently i did see a library with a animation behind the navigation- and status-bar.

It was something like a colored-background that did horizontally became another color along the loading.

When i needed it the most i couldn't find it again and have searched a lot on google. Have anyone here seen that library? I would give you 74 good wishes and a smile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a coding related spot,
Still.... The cool effects for UINavigationBar are https://github.com/CooperRS/RMStepsController and https://github.com/mwkoelb/MWKProgressIndicator

Answer (score 1):

## MWKProgressIndicator

https://github.com/mwkoelb/MWKProgressIndicator

This one ?